# Visual Basic Excel - Crear Carpetas usando 2 columnas

Tags: excel, vba

Soy nuevo en el Visual Basic 6 y tengo un problema.

Necesito crear carpetas usando dos columnas, es decir, en cada carpeta me tiene que aparecer el contenido de A1 y F1 separados por un guion bajo, por ejemplo, y así sucesivamente.

Buscando por foros y YouTube he encontrado:

```
Sub CrearCarpetas()
    ruta = InputBox("INGRESAR LA RUTA")
    Range("A2").Select

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
       MkDir (ruta & "/" & ActiveCell.Value)
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Y similares, que están muy bien pero solo sirven para una columna. yo lo que necesito es, partiendo de un ejemplo básico de una hoja de excel:

```
Nombre Apellido Otros
1      a        mm
2      s        nn
3      d        pp
4      f        kk
```

Quiero crear carpetas con el contenido de A2_C2, A3_C3, etc... He intentado con cosas random del estilo:

```
Sub CrearCarpetas2()
    ruta = InputBox("INGRESAR RUTA")

    Dim fila1 As String, fila2 As String

    fila1 = Range("A2").Select
    fila2 = Range("C2").Select

    If Dir(fila1 & fila2) = Empty Then
        MkDir (ruta & "/" & fila1 & "_" & fila2)
    End If
End Sub
```

Pero se crea una carpeta con valores verdadero_verdadero. ¿Sugerencias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, hay varios problemas.

El primero es el desconocimiento de las macros de Excel escritas en VBA. Por ello te recomiendo que te vayas mirando la documentación de Excel: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range%28object%29 (en este caso hemos usado el objeto Range que tiene una propiedad llamada Cells, que te devuelve matrices bidimensionales con el valor de cada columna-fila).

Si se desconoce la terminología: método, propiedad, objeto, matrices, recomiendo un curso de programación básico. También recomiendo en este caso, que tiendas a pensar como un programador, básicamente, según el objetivo que quieras cumplir, ir segmentando los problemas en problemas más pequeños. Si necesitas que se creen tantas carpetas como filas haya subyacen dos problemas, el primero saber el número de filas a leer y el segundo como leer dichos valores.

Lo segundo, el código que has encontrado en YouTube actualmente solo funciona para una columna básicamente por como está enfocado. Básicamente, lo que supongo que este hará será ir seleccionando las filas y sacando el valor de la celda actual. Se puede enfocar con ese código, pero habría que modificar `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` donde 0 se cambiaría por el número de destino, si estamos en la celda A pues tendriamos que ir hasta F, es decir, 5 celdas hacia la derecha.

Por ello, para no hacerlo muy complicado la solución sería esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsZBZ.gif

```
Option Explicit

'Dim ruta As String

Sub CrearCarpetas()

'ruta = InputBox("INGRESAR LA RUTA")

Dim lRow As Long

'Busca la ultima columna sin valor en la columna A(1)
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'El objeto cells devuelve una matriz de 2 dimesiones,
                                          'donde el primer parametro representa el rango de filas a coger y el segundo el numro de columnas
                                          'Con el metodo End lo que haremos será ir, en este caso, a la última celda
                                          'https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/
Dim i As Integer

'Iteramos empezando desde A2 hasta A[x] donde x es el número de celdas
For i = 2 To lRow
    MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & "_" & Cells(i, 2).Value)
    'Vamos obteniendo los valores donde i es el número actual de la celda
    'Y donde 1 y 2 representan A y B, si es F, pues ya sería 6

    'MkDir(ruta & "/" & Cells(i, 1).Value & "_" & Cells(i, 2).Value)
Next i

End Sub
```

El código está explicado dentro de los comentarios de este.

Espero haber ayudado.